# jQuery UI won't format date according to expectation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-formatting

The following prints `Nov 30` on both Chrome and FF. I was expecting `Dec 01`.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $t = $.datepicker.formatDate("M dd", new Date("2014-12-01"));
  console.log($t);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: datepicker's timezone is the desired one?

Comment: yeah, probably got something to do with timezones

Comment: But, shouldn't timezone be client dependent? I mean one may access the server from 'any' timezone?

Comment: Try using `parseDate('M dd', '2014-12-01')`

Comment: When using `new Date()`, you need to specify if its UTC or local time in the formatting of the string. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338411/javascript-date-object-changes

Comment: @Papa, I ended up doing: var dateObject = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", theDateStr);
return $.datepicker.formatDate("M dd", dateObject); If you change your comment about parseDate to 'answer' I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `parseDate('M dd', '2014-12-01')`.